# Get sub list from a list in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a list in free marker as below:

```
 <#assign listVar = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4" ] />
```

From the above list I just want the sub list as v1 and v2.

I have been wandering to get the sub list in free marker. But couldn't managed to find.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Might be helpful [link1](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/template-engines/freemarker/split-the-string-and-get-substrings-by-index.html),[link2](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/Splitting-a-list-and-adding-elements-td3341910.html)

Comment: I think this snippet gives an idea for your requirement               <#list listVar as x>
  ${x}
  <#if x = "v2"><#break></#if>
</#list>

Comment: But, I don't want to get sub list based on the content of the list. Rather I want based on indexes of list. Do have any idea?

Answer (score 14):

If you really want to make that slice based on indexes:

```
<#assign listVar = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4" ] />
<#assign sublistVar = listVar[0..1] />
```

See [Freemarker Sequence slicing](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_seqenceop_slice).

But beware, it will stop with error if the index is out of range. Depending on what you need this for, you may want to use `?chunk(2)` instead.

**Update:** As of avoiding index-out-of-bounds error, in FreeMarker 2.3.21 you can issue `listVar[0..*2]`, which will slice out 2 items, or less if there's less available. (Also exclusive-end slicing can come handy: `listVar[0..<2]`)

Comment: you saved my day.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Could you please mention this in both [built-ins](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html) and [sequence directives](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)? With a keywords `subsequence` and `sublist`. And with a link to [this](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_seqenceop_slice). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` variable when you list the sequence.

```
<#assign listVar = ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4" ] />
<#list listVar as aVar>
    <#if aVar_index > 2><#break/></#if>
</#list>
```

You can also partition the sequence using `chunk`. This will split the sequence in multiple sequences of the given size.

```
<#assign partitions = listVar?chunk(2) />
<#assign firstPartition = partitions?first />
```

Source: [FreeMarker Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html)

However, it is better to filter the data before passing it to the template.